# Why doesn't switching back to master from a branch change my files?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I created a branch called `test`.

```
git branch test
git checkout test
```

Then I made a bunch of changes. Added files, changed files, ect.

When I `checkout` `master` all the branch changes are still there. I thought the code would go back to the way it was before I branched? Am I not understanding the branching concept correctly?

I'm using Visual Studio and the Git plugin found here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never mention committing, only changing and adding. Any changes you haven't committed go along with you when you check out a branch. If you want changes to stay with a particular branch, you have to commit them before moving to a different branch. Otherwise, if you just want to temporarily hide the changes, you can use [`git stash`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html) to stow them away and `git stash pop` to bring them back later (on any branch).

Comment: Ah, Ok. I never committed anything. Thank you.

Comment: One nit: It is not that they "come with you", the new files are totally unknown to git, and it doesn't touch them at all. If you change some file that git knows about, you can switch branches and the modified file stays as it is (there is no conflict with changes to your original on the master branch), and could now be `commit`ed there.

Comment: @vonbrand: True. I was trying not to go too deep into the weeds on what seems to be a beginner-level question.

Answer (score 0):

When you added, changed, etc those files did you commit them? If you don't commit them and then move to another branch they come with you. For those cases in which you don't want to commit because the changes are not done are whatever you have the possibility to stash them. Using git stash you store the changes in the stash section and you can take them back later when you come back to the branch